# Why is using host memory recommended by docker

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I am investigating a topic, which I will call “Docker swarm and memory management”.

It states in this article [here](https://success.docker.com/article/node-using-swap-memory-instead-of-host-memory) that docker does not recommend using swap memory, but I can’t find (googling) a place where disadvantages of using swap memory in docker context is explained.

Can a kind soul enlighten me? :-)

Answer (score 1):

It is normal to disable SWAP memory in ALL applications or services that are used in production.

SWAP memory is based on using the hard disk as a substitute when the RAM is full. This may seem beneficial but the RAM has a speed from **2.1 GB/s** the **oldest** to **25.6 GB/s** the **newest**. Contrary to the speed of a hard drive with HDDs on average at **135MB/s**, newer M.2 SSDs at **1.2GB/s**.

As we can see we would be greatly slowing down the service if we were using SWAP.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was hoping on a answer like “random containers will get killed, if there is too many writes and reads, because it will timeout, ....” I think more an answer in docker context, but maybe there is none and it is a good practice that is mentioned in the article.